# creating multi records from xml file in Quickblox custom object

Tags: xml, api, rest, quickblox

I have a list of different courses (hundreds) in XML format and I want to create multi records in a Quickblox custom object which is a table of courses. Each record is a course with fields such as Platform, Course_Name, Length, ImageURL, Start_Date etc.

After generating a session token and a signature, I was able to create one record using the command below by typing everything on the command-line. However, I need your help to figure out how to use the XML file to create the records in an automated fashion. I was not able to figure this out from the Quickblox documentation on creating multi records

http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects#Create_multi_records

```
curl -X POST -H "QB-Token: 3842d6da71378aecd8409e8c68f" -d "Platform=Open2Study& \
Course_Name=Writing for the Web (WriteWeb)&University=open2study&Instructor=Frankie Madden& \
Length=4 weeks&Subject=Open 2 Study&GameModeID=3059&Language=English&
ImageURL=https://www.open2study.com/sites/default/files/styles/course_logo& \
VideoURL=https://www.youtube.com/embed/1ZzdrglOnDg?wmode=opaque& \
LinkURL=https://www.open2study.com/courses/writing-for-the-web& \
Prerequisites=All are welcome&Country=Australia& \
Summary=Find out how content can impact the reader's experience, as well as how the reader's 
experience can impact the way they interpret online content.& \
Efforts=Self study&SignupURL=https://www.open2study.com/enrol/319& \
Start_Date=18 Feb 2014&Type_of_certificate=Certificate of Achievement" https://api.quickblox.com
/data/tblCourses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to create milti records in single query:

```
curl -X POST -H "QB-Token: 281a7bc7c2984763ce77cda1b3641e551b93f887" -d "record[1][Platform]=...&record[1][Course_Name]=...&record[2][Platform]=...&record[2][Course_Name]=...&record[3][Platform]=...&record[3][Course_Name]=..." https://api.quickblox.com/data/tblCourses/multi
```

Comment: Since I already have all the info in XML format, is it possible to provide the url to the XML file so that this info is extracted from the XML file? Here is an example url [](https://www.open2study.com/courses.xml)

Comment: No, it isn't possible. You must parse your xml file and then make the correct request like in documentation.